# prompt before exit program in TideSDK/TideKIT

Tags: tidesdk, tidekit

I was looking for a way to tell the app to confirm if you really want to close the app before losing the changes of the project.

Through the current API, I was not able to do it. Looking on how Air/Flex do that, it looks like an event listener of the window when closing:

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   maxHeight="1080"
                   maxWidth="1920"
                   minWidth="1280"
                   minHeight="720" 
                   showStatusBar="false" 
                   creationComplete="startUp()"
                   closing="closeWindow(event)"
                   >
```

when I close the window through the Window interface or through the application menu, it executed what I was expecting, a prompt before the window close

```
Do you want to exit the application?/Do you want to exit without saving changes?
yes no.
```

Do TideSDK/TideKIT have this behavior? if so, please attach an example. It is very important for me to understand how to do it properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example helped me to do something similar in my TideSDK app:
https://gist.github.com/MisterPoppet/4639473

Pulling from the example there you may be able to do something like below to accomplish what you are asking:

```
var appWindow = Ti.UI.getCurrentWindow();

appWindow.addEventListener(Ti.CLOSE, function(event) {
    var r = confirm("Do you want to exit the application?");
    if (r == true) {
        //close
    } else {
        //cancel close
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Erick The above example is a good way to do this currently. TideKit will have compatible APIs with TideSDK so it can be the same if you are porting a project from TideSDK to TideKit. We'll be advocating the use of CommonJS for modular code for your new projects. Documentation will be available to help you get started with this approach once TideKit is launched publicly.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be testing this soon.

Comment: `if (r == true)` brought to you by the department of redundancy department.